# Creating DEM from point data in CSV files using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem

how can we create a DEM in QGIS from point data in CSV files? A similar problem was discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118243/how-can-i-create-an-dem-from-point-data), using a shp-file. Our CSV's are too big, so that dxf2shp crashes. So we are looking for another way to do this.

Comment: Had the same issue some time ago and used GRASS GIS sucessfully, as proposed by the answer to my question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140683/proof-low-deviations-in-dem-compared-to-point-dataset

Comment: "Our CSV's are too big, so that dxf2shp crashes".A dxf and a CSV are different things. Try to load your points with the add delimited text layer option, assing the proper coordinate system and save your points as a shape file (I am assuming they have some sort of z value). The you can use the interpolation option in the raster menu

Comment: @tareq: Thanks a lot. But ... too many errors while installing GRASS. I just found it why:  CURRENT GRASS BINARIES MAY NOT WORK WITH EL CAPITAN - OS X 10.11....  So I have to search for a solution with QGIS...

Comment: are you able to [install SAGA GIS on El Capitan](https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/wiki/Compiling%20SAGA%20on%20Mac%20OS%20X/)? If so, it should let you do this quite easily. Also, what do you mean by a large file, how many points (lines)?

Comment: @StevenKay: There are more 100k lines. If I convert it to DXF, then the DXF is more than 300 MB... SAGA GIS: I try to install it right now, using fink, but I can see a huge amount of warnings ....

Answer (score 1):

While I can't be certain without seeing your files and knowing the number of lines etc. you should be able to do this using the [`gdal_grid` utility.](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html)